# Does matrix contain a vector?

Tags: matlab

I'm looking for a fast / concise way to check whether some matrix contains given vector, e.g.:

```
 bigMatrix = [1 1 1; 2 2 2; 4 4 4; 5 5 5];

 someFunction(bigMatrix, [1 1 1]) % = true
 someFunction(bigMatrix, [3 3 3]) % = false
```

Is there such function/operator, or I need a loop?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would suggest the following solution:

```
bigMatrix = [1 1 1; 2 2 2; 4 4 4; 5 5 5];
Vec = [2 2 2];
Index = ismember(bigMatrix, Vec, 'rows');
```

The result?

```
Index =

 0
 1
 0
 0
```

`ismember` is an incredibly useful function that checks whether the elements of one set are in another set. Here, I exploit the rows option to force the function to compare rows, rather than individual elements.

**UPDATE:** On the other hand, it is always worth doing a few speed tests! I just compared the `ismember` approach to the following alternative method:

```
N = size(bigMatrix, 1);
Index2 = zeros(N, 1);
for n = 1:N
    if all(bigMatrix(n, :) == Vec)
        Index2(n) = 1;
    end
end
```

My findings? The size of `bigMatrix` matters! In particular, if `bigMatrix` is on the small side (somewhat of a misnomer), then the loop is much faster. The first approach is preferable only when `bigMatrix` becomes big. Further, the results are also dependent on how many columns `bigMatrix` has, as well as rows! I suggest you test both approaches for your application and then go with whichever is faster. (**EDIT**: This was on R2011a)

**General Note:** I am continually surprised by how much faster Matlab's loops have gotten in the last few years. Methinks vectorized code is no longer the holy grail that it once was.

Comment: Seems just what I'm looking for, thanks! And I can use it in conditional statement like: *if (find(Index == 1)), disp('true'); end;* (if there's more elegant way, TIA for the tip)

Comment: @buli Perhaps `if any(Index); disp('True'); end;` (that will display 'True' if there are any matches). Also, if you haven't read the updated version of my answer yet, I recommend doing so as I found the results quite interesting. ps glad I could help :-)

Comment: +1 for the interesting answer... you made me check in my machine where the line passes between `ismember` and the for loop (I'm a heavy `ismember` user)

Comment: @natan Glad you found it useful. And thanks for getting the answer score up to 10 :-)